Tikz diagram is broken
Under the code above, I tried to write the following diagram. However, the diagram is completely broken and does not display properly. Where should I improve and what kind of code should I type to display it correctly?
\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart} \usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel} \usepackage{url,xspace,smfthm}
%\usepackage{amsthm} \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools} %\usepackage{amscd}%
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem} \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage{amsthm} \DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma} \newtheorem{cor}{Cor}
\newtheorem{remark}{remark}

\usetikzlibrary{cd,bbox}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ column sep={5em,between origins}, row sep=5ex, bezier
bounding box,% <-- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619994/ ] 0
\arrow[r] & \Sha(E/K)[2] \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & A[2] \arrow[r,"f"]
\arrow[d] & B[2] \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & \text{Coker}f \arrow[r]
\arrow[d,"g"] & 0 \\ 0 \arrow[r] & \Sha(E/K) \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & A
\arrow[r,"i"] \arrow[d] & B\arrow[r] \arrow[d] & {\widehat{E(K)}}^* \\
& \text{ker}j \arrow[r]
\arrow[rrruu,in=150,out=170,looseness=2.6,"\delta"] & \dfrac{A}{A[2]}
\arrow[r,"j"] & \dfrac{B}{B[2]} \end{tikzcd} \]$$

P.S. But after removing dvipdfmx, the following diagram which was fine before is broken, what is a problem?
{\footnotesize
\[\]
\require{}\begin{CD}
\text{ker}F@>>>\Sha(E/K)[2]@>>>
\text{ker}H\\
@VVV@VVV @VVV\\
H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K),E(L))@>\text{inf}>>H^1(G_K,E)[2]@>\text{res}>>\text{res}(H^1(G_K,E)[2])\\
@VVFV @VVGV @VVH V \\
 \bigoplus_{v\in M_K}H^1(\text{Gal}(L_w/K_v),E(L_w))}}@>a>>\bigoplus_{v\in M_K} {H^1(G_{K_v},E)}}[2]@>>>\bigoplus_{v\in M_K}{\text{res}(H^1(G_{K_v},E}})[2]) \\
@VVV @VbVV \\
\text{coker}F@>j>>\Zhe \\ \]}


Please correct your example. There is no \begin/end{document} And what is that $$ doing at the end?

If I complete your code example (that is, removing $$ from the last line, adding \begin{document} and \end{document}, and moving ] 0 from behind the comment to a new line), I get a diagram that looks fine. Please tidy up and complete your code, make it minimal but compilable and tell us exactly, what goes wrong at your side.

With proper formatting and removing the packages that are incompatible with smfart, but also compiling with
latex <filename> && dvipdfmx <filename>

I get, note the addition of the TikZ library babel,
\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{url,xspace,smfthm}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}{Cor}
\newtheorem{remark}{remark}

\usetikzlibrary{cd,bbox,babel}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  column sep={5em,between origins},
  row sep=5ex,
  bezier bounding box,% <-- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619994/
]
0 \arrow[r] &
\Sha(E/K)[2] \arrow[r] \arrow[d] &
A[2] \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d] &
B[2] \arrow[r] \arrow[d] &
\Coker f \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"g"] &
0
\\
0 \arrow[r] &
\Sha(E/K) \arrow[r] \arrow[d] &
A \arrow[r,"i"] \arrow[d] &
B\arrow[r] \arrow[d] & {\widehat{E(K)}}^* \\
& \ker j \arrow[r]
\arrow[rrruu,in=150,out=170,looseness=2.6,"\delta"]
 &
\dfrac{A}{A[2]} \arrow[r,"j"] & \dfrac{B}{B[2]}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}


If you compile with pdflatex you must remove the dvipdfmx option when loading graphicx.
I added also proper formatting for “Coker” and “ker”. Don't use \text for that purpose.

I still cannot compile the diagram, output is just empty page. I'm using pdflatex.

@BrauerManinobstruction If you use pdflatex you MUST remove the dvipdfmx option. Did you?

Wow, that's cool... Thanks to your advice, a beautiful diagram has emerged. I am truly grateful for your insight and reliability.

But at the same time after I removed dvipdfmx, the diagram I wrote in P.S. broken, Where did I go wrong ?

@BrauerManinobstruction Then you cannot compile with pdflatex, but need the “latex+dvipdfmx” route.
